# Codeigniter inserting data into 2 tables

Tags: codeigniter

i already tried different ways and some post here
the 1st data is working savings to acadans_tbl but the update who's user login is not working.

view_file

```
         <td><input type="text" name="assessval" id="assessval" value="1"></td>
```

Controller

```
         $data1 = array(

         'Studnum' => $this->session->userdata['snum'],
         'Department' => $this->session->userdata['dept'],
         'Course' => $this->session->userdata['course'],
         'answer1' => $this->input->post('answer1'),
         'answer2' => $this->input->post('answer2'),
         'answer3' => $this->input->post('answer3'),
         'answer4' => $this->input->post('answer4'),
         'answer5' => $this->input->post('answer5'),
         'answer6' => $this->input->post('answer6'),
         'answer7' => $this->input->post('answer7'),
         'answer8' => $this->input->post('answer8'),
         'answer9' => $this->input->post('answer9'),
         'answer10' => $this->input->post('answer10')

        );

        $data2 = array(
        'assessval' => $this->input->post('assessval')
        );

        if ($this->Questions_model->create_ans($data1, $data2)) {
```

MODEL

```
    public function create_ans($data1, $data2) {
    $this->db->insert('acadans_tbl', $data1);

    $data2['assesed'] = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('users', $data2);

    }
```

Comment: Do you have `assessval` field in `users` table?

Comment: @tpojka i already change the field $data2 = array(
        'assesed' => $this->input->post('assessval')
        );

Comment: i have "assesed" field in users table

Comment: Well, that is the reason then. You specified `'assessval' => $this->input->post('assessval')` but your field in DB table is named differently actually.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller, you write:

```
    $data2 = array(
    'assessval' => $this->input->post('assessval')
    );
```

Its mean that you will insert the value from `$this->input->post('assessval')` to field `assessval` in the database. So, you have to ensure in the `users` table you have `assessval` field.

And in your model, just insert to the database:

```
$this->db->insert('users', $data2);
```